# Schengen overstay 1 day

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

I have a Schengen visa for Hungary from 24-28 March, but have air tickets that depart on 29th of March at 6 pm.

Will I be allowed or is there any problem if I overstayed 1 day?

Answer (score 5):

You will likely be able to board the plane, but unlikely to be allowed back into the Schengen again. If at all possible, change the flight back, or get a new flight, that will allow you to leave on the 28th.

Comment: I don't think any Schengen country is likely to issue a permanent ban over a 1-day overstay.  The risk of being denied entry strikes me as much more of a problem.

Comment: @phoog, agreed. The overstay will be in the record and the next visa application will likely be rejected *after* looking at the records, not before.